# Sublime Text 3 : Switch to Next File in Stack while in Column Layout

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I’m using Sublime Text version 3.2.2, Build 3211

In a 1 column Layout with 3 tabs, I can use **Goto > Switch File > Next File in Stack**

How can I achieve this while in a column layout?  **View > Layout > Columns:3**

Answer (score 0):

```
opt + Cmnd + left/right arrow key
```